# sprite kit : contact not working

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am trying to make one simple game and this problem happen first my paddle can touch the ball but now it cant do that and
this code also should  give me message or in simulator but it is not showing any idea?

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene , SKPhysicsContactDelegate{

var istouchingpaddle = false

let ballcatagery:UInt32 = 0 * 1 << 0
let paddlecategary :UInt32 = 0 * 1 << 1


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)

    border.friction = 0
    self.physicsBody = border
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,-9.8)
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    let ball = childNodeWithName ("ball") as SKSpriteNode
    ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(30, -30))
    ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1

    ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0



    ball.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ballcatagery
    let paddle = childNodeWithName("paddle") as SKSpriteNode
    paddle.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = paddlecategary
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = paddlecategary




}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ballcatagery && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == paddlecategary{

            println("working ")
    }

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    var touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    var location  = touch.locationInNode(self)
    if let body = self.physicsWorld.bodyAtPoint(location){
    if body.node!.name == "paddle" {

        istouchingpaddle = true
    }
    }


}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    if istouchingpaddle{
    var touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    var location  = touch.locationInNode(self)
    var prevlocation = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)
    var paddle = childNodeWithName("paddle") as SKSpriteNode
    var position = paddle.position.x + (location.x - prevlocation.x)
    position = max(position,paddle.size.width/2)
    position = min(position, size.width - paddle.size.width/2)



    paddle.position = CGPoint(x: position, y: paddle.position.y)


            }
}


override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    istouchingpaddle = false
}
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can produce good results with your code if I change the way of defining categories. Try setting categories like this :

```
let ballcatagery: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0 // Not that you have misspelled word "category", which can lead to errors if you expect somewhere a word "category" instead of your actual "categary". 
let paddlecategary : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
```

I can post you the whole code , but you should be good with this.

Comment: @DivyPatel You are welcome :) Note that 0x1 is not the same as 0*1 (0 times 1). 0x1 is a hexadecimal representation of 1.